# how i can extract the labels from my csv file

Tags: keras, label, training-data

can any one tell me what is the error i m using mnits data with 400 additional images label as 10,11,13,14 when i m extracting labels from csv file it will give me error. as below

> line 34, in to_categorical
>   categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
>
> IndexError: index -2147483648 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

trains.csv contains 60400 images
600000 thousand original mnist images and 400 images prepared by me

```py
data_train = pd.read_csv('mnistdata/mnist_train1.csv')

data_test = pd.read_csv('mnistdata/mnist_test.csv')

X forms the training images, and y forms the training labels
X = np.array(data_train.iloc[:, 1:])

y = to_categorical(np.array(data_train.iloc[:, 0]))
```

Here I split original training data to sub-training (80%) and validation data (20%)

```py
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=13)

X_test forms the test images, and y_test forms the test labels

X_test = np.array(data_test.iloc[:, 1:])

y_test = to_categorical(np.array(data_test.iloc[:, 0])
)
img_rows, img_cols = 28,28

input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
```

Prepare the training images

```py
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)

X_train = (X_train.astype('float32'))

X_train /= 255
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback, it will tell us which line produces the error

Comment: thank you i solved the issue  its because of some missing   label in training data